# Set permission for volume data that mount to a container?

Tags: apache, docker

I want to run a apache container to run code from bind mount vloume (`./src:/var/www/html`) in host.
I got a permission denied, then I attach to container and change owner to `apache:apache`, it works.
But I want to change the owner or permission without attach to container when build stack.

Comment: Build a `chown` command into your container startup scripts.

Comment: Configure the UID and GID of apache:apache to be the same as the UID and GID of the docker run user.